# Dependency Bean injection for generic instance variable in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using Spring 4.1.5-RELEASE and java 8 for my application. On looking at the class, there are 2 parametrizations to be considered, one at class level and other at class's instance variable. On dependency injection I am not having trouble for class level parametetrization ( as I have constructor with super()), while the instance variable serviceErrorResponseProcessor, causes following error. If serviceErrorResponseProcessor variable is removed from class and bean injection, I am not seeing the error. So something is wrong in defining the generic instance variable.

Class:

```
public class ServiceResponseProcessor implements ResponseProcessor<T, R> {

private ErrorResponseProcessor<Error> serviceErrorResponseProcessor;
private ServiceInfoResponseProcessor serviceInfoResponseProcessor;

// respective getters and setters
}
```

Bean injection:

```
<bean id="responseProcessor"
    class="com.path.ServiceResponseProcessor">
    <property name="serviceErrorResponseProcessor" ref="beanServiceErrorResponseProcessor" />
    <property name="serviceInfoResponseProcessor" ref="beanServiceInfoResponseProcessor" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanServiceErrorResponseProcessor"
    class="com.path.processor.ErrorResponseProcessor"/>

<bean id="beanServiceInfoResponseProcessor"
    class="com.path.processor.ServiceInfoResponseProcessor"/>
```

Error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'responseProcessor' defined in class path resource [config/bean-dependency.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at com.path.ServiceResponseProcessor.testResponseProcessor(ServiceResponseProcessor.java:326)
    at com.path.ServiceResponseProcessor.testSteps(ServiceResponseProcessor.java:276)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at com.path.ServiceResponseProcessor.testResponseProcessor(ServiceResponseProcessor.java:326)
    at com.path.ServiceResponseProcessor.testSteps(ServiceResponseProcessor.java:276)
```

Comment: Why are you using Spring 4.1? It's entirely obsolete. Updating to 4.3 should solve your problem.

Comment: @Chrylis my app is a legacy one, so its not easy to upgrade all at once. I will try your suggestion to upgrade.

Comment: I noticed that, which is why I didn't suggest an upgrade to 5.x, but 4.2 and 4.3 introduced substantial injection improvements here. (Also note that if your `Error` class is new, *change its name immediately*. **Never** name a class the same thing as a class in `java.lang`.)

Comment: If you mean <Error>, its not a new class, but a third party api. I did not add imports so that it does not crowd the page. Also This app has a dependency on another service that is using 4.1.5-RELEASE of spring so I am not able to use 4.2 and 4.3

Comment: Did you try upgrading anyway? Unless you're doing something *very* specific you shouldn't face any problems with forward compatibility within the 4.x series.

Comment: Before I tried to upgrade the following work around worked. I will be trying upgrade sometime today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found something which worked for me using spring 4.1.5-RELEASE, that is one cannot use generics in instance variable when the class where it is used for bean injection.

Class:

```
public class ServiceResponseProcessor implements ResponseProcessor<T, R> {

private ServiceErrorResponseProcessor serviceErrorResponseProcessor;
private ServiceInfoResponseProcessor serviceInfoResponseProcessor;

   // respective getters and setters
}
```

while,

```
ServiceErrorResponseProcessor implements ErrorResponseProcessor<Error>{
   // implementation
}
```

Bean injection:

```
<bean id="responseProcessor"
class="com.path.ServiceResponseProcessor">
<property name="serviceErrorResponseProcessor" ref="beanServiceErrorResponseProcessor" />
<property name="serviceInfoResponseProcessor" ref="beanServiceInfoResponseProcessor" />
```